# Formatting datetimes in Twig

Tags: symfony, formatting, twig

In my mySQL database, I have some date (`EventDate`) and time (`EventStartT` and `EventEndT`) variables that I trying to format for presentation.

Previously I was looping through the array of my query and applying presentation format as:

```
$fdate=date_format(date_create($row['EventDate']), "l jS \of F Y");
$stime=time_format($row['EventStartT'],"%H:%i");
```

This gave me:

- Friday 1st of November 2015
- 12:00 - 15:00

However, I'm now trying to rework the site using the Symfony Framework with Doctrine and Twig. I have the following in my twig template (where `list` is an array of all events returned):

```
{% block body %}
   {% for item in list %}
      <div class=''><strong>Date: {{ item.EventDate|date("l jS \of F Y") }} </strong></div>
      {% if item.EventStartT %} 
         <div class=''>Time:    {{ item.EventStartT|date("%H:%i") }} - {{  item.EventEndT|date("%H:%i") }} </div> 
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately neither are giving me the result I'm after as I'm getting:

- Friday 1st 2013f November 2015
- %00:%00 - %00:%00

Comment: Can you show us your controller and especially what's really inside `item.EventDate` and `EventStartT` ? You may be formatting the dates twice ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are mixing to formats. The first one is correct, the second is from strftime, but the `date` filter uses the php `date` format.

Simply remove the `%`:

```
item.EventStartT|date('H:i')
```

Of course your `$row['EventStartT']` must be a `\DateTime` instance.